# Download SFTP File in Azure for Decrypt

Tags: .net, azure, encryption, azure-functions, sftp

I have to download and decrypt a file from SFTP in Azure functions

```
using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(file.Name))
{
    
    client.DownloadFile(file.FullName, fileStream);
    fileStream.Close();                           
    DecryptFile(file.Name.ToString());
    fileName = file.Name;

}
```

getting error on this line:

```
using (Stream fileStream = File.OpenWrite(file.Name))
```

Error:

> Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Functions\4.14.0\32bit\

Need help as I am very new to Azure Functions.

Answer (score -1):

Uploaded file to azure.

[image]

**File downloaded.**

[image]

**Dowloading file using Sftp**

```
    using (var sftp = new SftpClient(Host, username, password))
            {
                sftp.Connect();
                SftpFileAttributes attrib = sftp.GetAttributes(file.Name);
                var ms = new MemoryStream();
                IAsyncResult asyncRes = sftp.BeginDownloadFile(file.Name, ms);
                SftpDownloadAsyncResult sftpAsyncr = (SftpDownloadAsyncResult)asyncRes;
                sftp.EndDownloadFile(asyncRes);
                Console.WriteLine("Writing File to localpath");
                string localFilePath = "C:\Temp" + file.Name;
                var fstream = new FileStream(localFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                ms.WriteTo(fstream);
               }
```

**Reading file to bytes and decrypting**

```
byte[] File_Bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(encryptedFilePath);
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypyedBytesArray)
```

Encryption or decryption using `Rsaoaep` algorithm.

```
            var inputString = "input some value";
            byte[] input = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputString);
            var encrypt_Result = cryptographyClient
                .Encrypt(EncryptionAlgorithm.RsaOaep, input);
            var encrypted_String = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypt_Result.Ciphertext);
            byte[] encryptedResult_Bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encrypted_String);
            cryptographyClient.Decrypt(EncryptionAlgorithm.RsaOaep, encryptedResult_Bytes);
```

**Normal downloading file using functions.**

```
var storage_Account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("ConnectionString");
            var Blobclient = storage_Account.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            var myContainer = Blobclient.GetContainerReference("sample");

            var cloudBlockBlob = myContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("sample.txt");

            await cloudBlockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(req.Body);


            string somename = req.Query["name"];

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
            somename = somename ?? data?.name;

            return somename != null
                ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Greetings to, {somename}")
                : new BadRequestObjectResult("Need to pass a string as a query string else as a request body");
```

Comment: There's no need to store the data to an intermediate temporary file. You already have the `byte[]` array in `ms.GetBuffer()`.